# User control with auto-height property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I want to create user control that will display text.
I need a way to resize control at run-time so that it will adjust height to show all the text.
I've created control that looks like this:

[image]

As You can see I have icon and text drawn using `TextRenderer.DrawText`. Unfortunately when I resize my control (only to left or right) my text is sometimes cut, ass shown below:

[image]

I'm measuring text using `TextRenderer.MeasureText` based on that I'm counting number of lines and then I'm drawing that text. Here is code I'm using:

```
[Designer(typeof(MyTextBoxDesigner))]
public partial class MyTextBox : UserControl
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DefaultValue("Demo"), Description("Text of control"), Category("Appearance"),Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.Text == value) return;
            base.Text = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    Image _image;
    [Description("Image shown on the left side of the control"),
    Category("Appearance")]
    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _image;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_image == value) return;
            _image = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int imagePadding = 0;
        if (_image != null)
        {
            imagePadding = 25;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image,new Rectangle(5,5,16,16));
        }
        Size textSize1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, Text, Font);
        SizeF textSize2 = e.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font);

        Debug.WriteLine(textSize2);

        int maxTextWidth = Width - Padding.Left-Padding.Right-imagePadding;
        int lineHeight = textSize1.Height + 2;
        int numLines = 1;

        if (textSize1.Width > maxTextWidth)
        {
            numLines = textSize1.Width / maxTextWidth + 1;
        }

        Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = Width - Padding.Left-Padding.Right-imagePadding,
            Height = (numLines * lineHeight),
            X = Padding.Left+imagePadding,
            Y = 5
        };

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, textRect, ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.Top);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.CadetBlue, textRect);

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}

internal class MyTextBoxDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public override SelectionRules SelectionRules
    {
        get
        {
            //all minus bottom and top
            return (base.SelectionRules & ~(SelectionRules.BottomSizeable | SelectionRules.TopSizeable));
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like my control to auto-adjust height based on text length, so if text is short (or control long enough) in will be for example 20px height, but if text is long my control should be (for example) 40px height (2 lines of text).

How should I change my text measurement to calculate `textRect` correctly?
Should I update height of my control using Size property or is there a better way?

**EDIT:**
Basically I want to draw text that can wrap inside rectangle, but has fixed width, so when text is longer that rectangle will adjust its height. Then based on that height I want to adjust control height.

Comment: cant you have scrollbar in the TextBox? set the ScrollBars, MultiLine and WordWrap properties according to your needs. To disable editing of the TextBox (and, thus, make it behave similar to a label), use the ReadOnly property.

Comment: how about simply using a label with maximum width and auto-size?

Comment: @SushilMate I'd like to avoid using other controls, I'd like to draw it using simple `onPaint` event

Comment: @ZoharPeled that's an option, but at first I'd like to try drawing everything inside `onPaint`.

Comment: re-inventing the wheel has it's downsides. The .Net class library programmers probably knows what they are doing, I would rather use whatever I can from the already existing controls then painting the text myself.

Comment: I shared an auto-height control control containing a `Lebel`. You can simply draw the image in `OnPaint` method. Also you can add a `PictureBox` for image. Hosting the `Label` in control simplifies the sizing logic and rendering codes.

Comment: I also shared another approach, creating the control from scratch without hosting any other controls. You can simply draw also the image.

Comment: These are not the only approaches available but are good examples. As another option you can inherit from a Label and change it's behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an auto-height control. If you change the width of control, the height of control will changes in way which the whole text can be shown.

[image]

You can create such control using different approaches including:

- **Approach 1: Auto-size Composite Control hosting a Label**
  This approach is based on hosting an auto-size `Label` with dynamic maximum width in an auto-size `Control`. In this approach we set maximum width of label based on width of control and since the label is auto-size, its height will be automatically set to show all texts and then we set height of control based on height of label.
- **Approach 2: Auto-Size Simple Control from scratch without Label**
  This approach is based on overriding [`SetBoundsCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore(v=vs.110).aspx) and setting size of control based on its `Text` size. In this approach we calculate the size of text based on width of control using [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext(v=vs.110).aspx) and then set calculated height as height of control. In this approach you should handle text format flags and rendering yourself.

In both approaches a `ControlDesigner` is used to disable all size grab handles except left and right.

**Please note**

These are not the only approaches available but are good examples. As another option you can inherit from a `Label` and change it's behavior.

### **Approach 1: Auto-size Composite Control hosting a Label**

It works based on setting `AutoSize` property of label to `true` and then setting `MaximumSize` of label based on contol `Width`. Also the height of control is set based on height of label.
You can simply draw the image in `OnPaint` method. Also you can add a `PictureBox` for image.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
[Designer(typeof(MyLabelDesigner))]
public partial class MyLabel : Control
{
    public MyLabel() { InitializeComponent(); }
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label textLabel;
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.textLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.textLabel.Name = "label1";
        textLabel.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(textLabel_SizeChanged);
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.Controls.Add(this.textLabel);
    }
    void textLabel_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Height = this.textLabel.Bottom + 0;
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        this.textLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, 0);
    }
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return this.textLabel.Text; }
        set { this.textLabel.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

### **Approach 2: Auto-Size Simple Control from scratch without Label**

This approach works based on setting size of control in `SetBoundsCore` based on current width and calculated height of its `Text`. To calculate height of control. You can simply draw the `Image`.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
[Designer(typeof(MyLabelDesigner))]
public class ExLabel : Control
{
    public ExLabel()
    {
        AutoSize = true;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        SetBoundsCore(Left, Top, Width, Height, BoundsSpecified.Size);
        Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height,
        BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        var flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
        var proposedSize = new Size(width, int.MaxValue);
        var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font, proposedSize, flags);
        height = size.Height;
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle,
            ForeColor, BackColor, flags);
    }
}
```

### **Designer**

Here is the `ControlDesigner` which used to limit size grab handles in designer to left and right for both implementations:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyLabelDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public override SelectionRules SelectionRules
    {
        get
        {
            return (base.SelectionRules & ~(SelectionRules.BottomSizeable | 
                                            SelectionRules.TopSizeable));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for both solutions. I want to avoid adding Label to my control so I'll probably choose Your second solution. I've tried overriding `SetBoundsCore` by my own, but I couldn't find how to get that text height. Thank You for that. I'll check that right away and will let You know if everything worked fine.

Comment: Approach two works fine except one thing - if I dock to top my control and resize form my control isn't painted correctly. I've added `DoubleBuffered=true` in constructor, I've tried setting styles using `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true)` but without luck. Is this because of overriding `SetBoundsCore`? Here is my result: http://i.imgur.com/45TR77P.png - I've resized my form couple of times

Comment: If you use the exact code which I used, there is no problem when you dock the control to top. So it seems the problem is in paint logic, specially because you put `base.OnPaint(e);` after all codes. Put it before all codes.

Comment: Great answer! I didn't even know about SetBoundsCore... I thought it's going to be a lot more code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've tried that, but my only option was to add `OnResize` event to my control and then call `Invalidate` here is my code so far: http://pastebin.com/Ke3U6qJq I'm not sure if this is needed (could You look at it?). I'll add couple more thing to my control (mouseover effect and show/close functionality) and then I'll post whole code on CodeReview so I'd be grateful for Your opinion.

Comment: @Misiu Oops, I didn't test the approach at run-time and I only had checked at design-time. You need to use `SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);`  to redraw the control after resize. This way you don't need to override `OnResize`. Also as you did for more smooth rendering  `DoubleBuffered = true;`. I edited the answer.

Comment: By the way, sorry about late reply, I totally had forgotten about your comment :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei now everything works perfect! Thank You for help!