# Fit-width custom control in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to have my custom control somehow auto-fit into the flow layout panel at horizontal edges.

What I am trying to accomplish is a vertical list of shown custom control. But what I get is below:

[image: Screenshot of VS Designer]

Code for my custom control is:

```
namespace CustomControl
{
    partial class ChatMessage
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ChatMessage));
            this.ContentsTable = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.DateTimeLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.NumberLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.NameLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.MessageLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.DirectionLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.ContentsTable.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // ContentsTable
            // 
            this.ContentsTable.AutoSize = true;
            this.ContentsTable.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.ContentsTable.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.ContentsTable.ColumnCount = 2;
            this.ContentsTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.ContentsTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.ContentsTable.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
            this.ContentsTable.Controls.Add(this.DateTimeLabel, 1, 2);
            this.ContentsTable.Controls.Add(this.NumberLabel, 1, 0);
            this.ContentsTable.Controls.Add(this.NameLabel, 0, 0);
            this.ContentsTable.Controls.Add(this.MessageLabel, 0, 1);
            this.ContentsTable.Controls.Add(this.DirectionLabel, 0, 2);
            this.ContentsTable.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.ContentsTable.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(48, 0);
            this.ContentsTable.Name = "ContentsTable";
            this.ContentsTable.RowCount = 3;
            this.ContentsTable.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
            this.ContentsTable.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
            this.ContentsTable.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
            this.ContentsTable.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(592, 54);
            this.ContentsTable.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // DateTimeLabel
            // 
            this.DateTimeLabel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.DateTimeLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.DateTimeLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
            this.DateTimeLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(299, 104);
            this.DateTimeLabel.Name = "DateTimeLabel";
            this.DateTimeLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(290, 20);
            this.DateTimeLabel.TabIndex = 0;
            this.DateTimeLabel.Text = "Date / Time";
            this.DateTimeLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            // 
            // NumberLabel
            // 
            this.NumberLabel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.NumberLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.NumberLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(299, 0);
            this.NumberLabel.Name = "NumberLabel";
            this.NumberLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(290, 20);
            this.NumberLabel.TabIndex = 1;
            this.NumberLabel.Text = "Number or ID";
            this.NumberLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            // 
            // NameLabel
            // 
            this.NameLabel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.NameLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.NameLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.NameLabel.Name = "NameLabel";
            this.NameLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(290, 20);
            this.NameLabel.TabIndex = 2;
            this.NameLabel.Text = "Name";
            this.NameLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            // 
            // MessageLabel
            // 
            this.MessageLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.ContentsTable.SetColumnSpan(this.MessageLabel, 2);
            this.MessageLabel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.MessageLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.MessageLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 20);
            this.MessageLabel.Name = "MessageLabel";
            this.MessageLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(586, 84);
            this.MessageLabel.TabIndex = 3;
            this.MessageLabel.Text = resources.GetString("MessageLabel.Text");
            // 
            // DirectionLabel
            // 
            this.DirectionLabel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.DirectionLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.DirectionLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 104);
            this.DirectionLabel.Name = "DirectionLabel";
            this.DirectionLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(290, 20);
            this.DirectionLabel.TabIndex = 4;
            this.DirectionLabel.Text = "Direction";
            this.DirectionLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            // 
            // ChatMessage
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.Controls.Add(this.ContentsTable);
            this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 0);
            this.Name = "ChatMessage";
            this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(48, 0, 0, 0);
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 54);
            this.ContentsTable.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ContentsTable.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel ContentsTable;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label DateTimeLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label NumberLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label NameLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label MessageLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label DirectionLabel;
    }
}
```

You can see my custom control overflows form size.
**Note:** Flow layout panel used in the picture has a dock fill, flow direction = top down & wrap contents = false.

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: add your custom control's code please

Comment: I laid it out using designer, code case in empty. Should i add *.Designer.cs code? Anyways, I added code @Stephen

Comment: You don't need `FlowLayoutPanel`, you just need a `Panel` and then just set `Dock` property of your user controls to `Top`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I may be adding around thousands of controls (one for each message) to the panel. Will it be performant?

Comment: Do you think if `FlowLayoutPanel` would be even a bit better? For large amount of messages I probably use a `WebBrowser` control instead and show messages using html or even a `DataGridView`

Comment: Nope, I didn't think about it. It was just a random question. I will check about performance when I compile it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei With dock = top on control inside panel, now width fits fine but height doesn't autosize and cuts contents.

Comment: Check the **Left Padding** on your form.

Comment: @Stephen the padding on left I added in the custom control, not in the form (you can check I code I posted) to make it feel like chat bubble. Form has no padding.

Comment: @vailbhav it seems like your message is not wrapping, if you are adding the message control dynamically, just ensure that you are auto-sizing it. other-wise it looks fine on my side

Comment: @VaibhavPandey You need to use `AutoScroll=true` for container `Panel`. Then the panel will add scrollbars when content goes beyond the boundary of panel.

Comment: Also it seems you need to make your [user control auto-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203411/user-control-with-auto-height-property).

Comment: Also don't neglect [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117528/fit-width-custom-control-in-flowlayoutpanel?noredirect=1#comment69440000_41117528).

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am also considering of doing the app wholly using Atom's Electron (html/css/js) but would prefer to check with performance in winforms first. And I accompalished what I wanted. I am answering the question with the solution for future references.

Comment: Good job. You will also find the auto-height control which I linked useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the custom label class from [this page](http://www.cyotek.com/blog/creating-a-windows-forms-label-that-wraps-with-csharp) for the message label inside panel as suggested by [@Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) did the job. See the result below, this is exactly what I wanted.

[image]